# Custom template

Tags: 7, theming

In my theme I created my template for all my pages (page.tpl.php):

[image]

What should I do to create a template for page /services for example, and this inherit all of page.tpl.php? but only write in the content region.

Comment: Your services page will be using page.tpl unless you have not added any tpl suggestion for it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but Drupal always renders the content in the "content" block region of page.tpl.php. The page template is already for every page.

If you want *other regions* to be different on a specific page, it depends on the method the specific page is generated. You could create overriding template files, but I would recommend keeping as much as possible that stays the same on every page in your page.tpl.php file and use other templates like node.tpl.php or block.tpl.php (block--region.tpl.php) for dynamic layouts and markup.